# Android Kotlin - socket.write or getOutputStream, flush closes connection

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

Another day another head scratcher.
Been trying to send ByteArray over TCP socket and get a response but when ever I write to socket in any shape or form it will not wait for response.

I set up a Packet Sender app that waits for connection on port and when connection from android device  occurs it should return some string.

So far I have two pieces of code....first one send but does not receive, second one does not send any data but triggers the response... im baffled.

Anyone can help me sort out this misery?

ok.. I see that two fragments is confusing so here is the one Im focused on right now

```
            Thread(Runnable {
                try {
                    d("TEST > Connect 2> IP:", IP.toString())
                    d("TEST > Connect 2> Port:", Port.toString())
                    d("TEST >> FINAL OUT 2>> ", hex)

                    val client = Socket(IP.toString(), Port)
                    //client.outputStream.write(hexOut(hex!!))

                    var pw = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                    pw.println("HERE")
                    //pw.flush()

                    var inData = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
                    d("TEST >> ", inData.toString())

                    //client.close()
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    d("TEST > ERROR 2>>> ", ex.toString())
                    Snackbar.make(mainView, "$ex", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE ).show()
                } finally {
                    d("TEST >> Sent done 2>"," for $hex")
                }
            }).start()
```

the result is that nothing except an open connection is made and nothing is sent to the server but there is return data. (GOT HERE)

TIME            From IP             From Port   To IP       To Port Method  ASCII       Hex

04:49:24.500    You (Response)      444         192.168.1.4 4642    TCP             GOT HERE    47 4F 54 20 48 45 52 45

04:49:19.500    192.168.1.4         4642        You         444     TCP

if I uncomment flush(), only message (HERE) is sent but there is no response. The same is true if printwriter is commended out and write is uncommented.

TIME            From IP         From Port   To IP   To Port Method  ASCII   Hex

04:53:09.107    192.168.1.4     4680        You     444     TCP             HERE\n  48 45 52 45 0A

The goal is to send data (HERE) and get response (GOT HERE). Ive tried every google search term that I could think off, tried with TCP classes tried a bunch of examples and it all comes down to this. Been stuck with this for more than I care to admit and I didnt ask this question without doing a bunch of googling and testing. 
I hope that its something simple and I will be kicking myself later.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Your sending code doesn't read anything. `inData.toString()` is not an I/O operation. Try `readLine()`, as you're sending a line from the second chunk. There is no evidence here of untoward closing.

Comment: the two code segments should do the same thing, connect to server, send some data and get it from server. Server is not android based and for testing Im using Pocket Sender https://packetsender.com/. You are right that the code reads nothing but thats not what Im having issue with. Its that first one sends data to server correctly but no data is sent back while the second one just opens a connection and sends nothing while it does triger the server to send back data. There is no conditions on the server when It should send data. It sends on receive of any

Comment: Im monitoring what is sent from PocketSender. I can see when app connects, sends data and what data is sent back. The first code fragment sends data but connection gets closed, the second code fragment sends no data (it should) but connection keeps open for data to be sent back to android app. Tried write, tried using printwriter, tried... I dont know what else to try

Comment: Define 'connection gets closed'. Show us a log. Answer my question about waiting for a response. Give us something here. The only difference between these two pieces of code is the difference between `write()` and `println()`, which you show no sign of understanding. While you're at it, please explain the claim about `flush()` in your title when there is no flushing in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry to have wasted your time...... It was my testing setup that was to blame.... so much time wasted.... well.. of to bed and thanks for your effort!